# Automatic hiding of areas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Based on previous answers to this question I wrote this code which doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "1" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!L:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "2" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!M:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "3" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!N:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "4" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!O:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "5" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!P:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "6" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!Q:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "7" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!R:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "8" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!S:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "9" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!T:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "10" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!U:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "11" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!V:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "12" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!W:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "13" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!X:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "14" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!Y:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "15" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!Z:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "16" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!AA:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "17" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!AB:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "18" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!AC:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "19" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!AD:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  ElseIf Range("'Paramètres clés du projet'!$H$25").Value = "20" Then
        Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!AD:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    End If
End Sub
```

--> What I want out of this code is to automatically hide an area of a sheet based on the value of a cell (drop-down menu from 0 to 20) in another sheet.

Could someone exlpain to me why my code doesn't work?

Thank you

Comment: What are those previous answers, can you add a link to them? How exactly it doesn't work? Do you get any error message?

Comment: first off, you need something to trigger the macro.  Select something from your dropdown and then go manually run the macro. If it does what you want then just need a way to tell it to start when you want.

Comment: @bvaughn The macro is triggering on change in the worksheet (like selecting something in the dropdown).

Comment: Try not specifying the sheet in columns. Instead of `Columns("'Feuille de calcul'!L:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` Try `Worksheets("Feuille de calcul").Columns("L:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Comment: why don't use a switch case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the target sheet inside `Columns()` like that isn't valid.
Try using
    `Worksheets("Feuille de calcul").Columns("L:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` instead.

You could also try something shorter and more dynamic. 
Instead of defining every value from the list, you can do something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cMin As Integer, cMax As Integer, cSave As Integer, i As Integer, ws As String
ws = "Feuille de calcul"                'Sheet to hide on.
cMin = 12                               'First column to hide on "1".   12 = "L"
cMax = 30                               'Last column to hide.           30 = "AD"

If Target.Address = "$H$25" Then        'Only updates the Hidden columns in `ws´ when the list is changed
    If Target.Value >= 1 And Target.Value <= 20 Then  'Only updates if list is between 1 and 20
        cSave = cMin
        Do                              'Loops through and unhides all columns between cMin and cMax
            Worksheets(ws).Columns(cMin).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            cMin = cMin + 1
        Loop While cMin <= cMax
        cMin = cSave
        i = Target.Value
        cMin = cMin + i - 1
        If cMin > cMax Then             'If "20" is chosen from the default list, we have gone past cMax
            cMin = cMax                 'So we set it to the last column
        End If
        Do                              'Loops through and hides all columns between cMin and cMax
            Worksheets(ws).Columns(cMin).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            cMin = cMin + 1
        Loop While cMin <= cMax
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, I did not include a reference to the sheet in which the list is.
This is because **this code is supposed to go in the code of that specific sheet**.
Now you can change the starting and ending column without having to rewrite the entire thing.
*Edited to first unhide all columns specified in the range of columns (cMin to cMax).*

Comment: Thank you very much Christofer, your code works perfectly. Now what would I need to add if I wanted the columns to unhide ?
Let's say I had "$H$25" = 2 but then I want to change it to "$H$25" = 8; how could the necessay columns unhide ?
Thank you again for your support !

Comment: @Hippolyte  The easiest way i think is to just unhide everything at the beginning of the code. If that is an option. You can use          `Worksheets(ws).Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False` and run this in the ifs. You can paste it above `i = Target.Value` .

Comment: Thank you again for your quick reply.

So you mean that I should add it here ? :

If Target.Address = "$H$25" Then
If Target.Value >= 1 And Target.Value <= 20 Then
If Worksheets(ws).Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
i = Target.Value

Thank you

Comment: @Hippolyte Sounds about right. I'll edit it in to the answer so that you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Hippolyte You could also run the hide loop at an earlier stage without adding the value of the list, but with `.Hidden = False` to unhide the specific rows. This is slightly trickier, but can be useful if you for some reason want to hide other rows in that sheet, unrelated to this macro. Otherwise those will get unhidden as well.

Comment: Yes indeed, it did unhide the columns I was hiding already. Sorry, where did you recommend to insert the  .Hidden = False ? I'm not sure I understood.
Or do you have another way to specifically unhide the columns from 12 et 30 ?

Thank you

Comment: @Hippolyte Updated the answer to only unhide the specific columns. I just run the same loop (but with *false*) before adding the value of the list, to make sure I get all columns. Then I reset rMin to the original value, since it's used in the loop.

Comment: @Hippolyte Glad to hear it. Just ask if there is something you need explained or anything. And feel free to upvote if you like ;)

Comment: Thank you. The code is a bit complicated to me based on my current knowldge of VBA but i'll definitely keep looking at it to understand better the underlying magic haha

Sorry I can't upvote your post as I don't have enough "reputation" on the website. Anyway, thank you again for this awesome code !

Comment: @ChristoferWeber:  I believe that `rMin`, `rMax`, and `rSave` should be `cMin`, `cMax`, and `cSave`, because they are ***column*** numbers.  (A few of the comments are wrong, too.)

Comment: @Scott I agree. Not sure if I was initially thinking range, but I've clearly written row in the comments, which is wrong.